# Unix Script Convert CSV into XLSX

Tags: excel, perl, csv, unix

I am trying to convert CSV file into XLSX.

I have done successfully in XLS before but when trying to do in XLSX , I keep getting errors.

This is sample script I am trying to execute.

https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/blob/master/examples/a_simple.pl

I have included all these Lib in my script :-
!/usr/bin/perl -w

use lib qw(/Scripts/perl/excel-writer-xlsx-master/lib);

use lib qw(/Scripts/perl/File-Temp-0.19/lib);

use lib qw(/Scripts/perl/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib);

use lib qw(/Scripts/perl/IO-1.25/lib);

use lib qw(/Scripts/perl/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.069/lib);

**Error :-
Can't locate loadable object for module Compress::Raw::Zlib in @INC 
Compilation failed in require  /Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line** 12

XLS working successfully with this package: Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40

Perl XLSX Module downloaded from

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm

Comment: I have highlighted the Error .

Comment: It looks like you've just unpacked the tar files downloaded from CPAN. That's not how you install Perl modules. In particular, modules like Compress::Raw::Zlib that are written in C need to be compiled during installation. Have a read of: [How to install CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).

Answer (score 2):

The paths you're specifying in these `use lib` statements look wrong. Make sure that you have actually installed these modules (i.e, using the `cpan` or `cpanm` tools). Simply unpacking the tarballs from the CPAN web site is not sufficient, and will not work, as some of these modules must be compiled to function.

Once you've installed these modules correctly, they should be available on the default Perl `@INC` path, and you will not need to use any extra `use lib` lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a python script which convert any ff - flat file to required file format. csv2xls.py
Ref link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csv2xls/0.4